# Increment the current value with the last value of an long int - arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to increment the current value of a time interval3 (mills) with the last value of the same time interval3, can help ?

```
int V1;
int V2;
int V3;

long int time1; 
long int time2; 
long int time3; 

long int interval1; 
long int interval2; 
long int interval3;  


void setup() {
  pinMode(2, INPUT); 
  pinMode(3, INPUT); 
  pinMode(4, INPUT); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {  
  
  V1 = digitalRead(2); 
  V2 = digitalRead(3); 
  V3 = digitalRead(4); 

   if (V1 == HIGH & V2 == LOW) { 
    Serial.println("Event0");
    time1 = millis();   // current value time 1
  
  if (V2 == HIGH & V1 == LOW) {
    Serial.println("Event1 ");
    time2 = millis();
    interval1 = (time2 - time1)/60000;                         /// Waiting time 1
    delay(500);
  }

  if (V3 == HIGH & V1 == LOW & V2 == LOW) {
    Serial.println("Event2 ");
    time3 = millis();
    delay(500);
    interval2 = (time3 - time2)/60000;                        // Witing time 2
    interval3 =interval1+interval2;                           // total time
    Serial.print("Total Time Event1+Event2");
    Serial.print(interval3);   // in this "if" I want to increment the "interval3" with the last value.
  }

}
}
```

I was thinking for a solution like:

```
if (interval3 != millis && interval3){;
        interval3 = currTimetd;
    unsigned long currTimetd = millis();
    unsigned long totaldowntime = (currTimetd+lastTimetd)/60000;
    lastTimetd = currTimetd;
    Serial.print("Total downtime: ");
    Serial.println(totaldowntime);
    Serial.println("----------------------------------------");
    }
```

Unfortunately I cannot use the "the interval3 in a function".

Can you help me with some hints in order to increment the current value of the interval3 with the last one value ?
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: For starters: your first `if` is missing a closing bracket, and `time1`, `time2`, and `time3` should be `unsigned long int`s, and for a logical AND you should use `&&` and not `&`.

Comment: Yes you have right, I wrote the code for the purpose of understanding the environment of my problem. Im sure that those hints are not a solution for my incremental task. Thank you !